# TypeError: bad operand type for unary -: 'tuple'

Tags: python

Pythonプログラミング作業をGoogle Colab上でしており、下記記事に記載されたコードをそのまま打ち込む作業をしています。

https://shoichimidorikawa.github.io/Miscellaneous/K-M.pdf

そこでエラーが表示されたのですが、検索しても解決策が見つけられずこちらに投稿した次第です。

エラーは、11行目について `TypeError: bad operand type for unary -: 'tuple'` と表示されています。何をどのように修正するとよいのか、どなたかご教示いただけますでしょうか。

```
# Kermac & MacKecdric equations
import scipy
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# S/N=y[0], I/N=y[1], R/N=y[2]
# R0 = \beta N/\gamma
R0=1,3
def func (t,y):
  dydt = np.zeros_like(y)
  dydt[0] = -R0*y[0]*y[1]
  dydt[1] = (R0*y[0]-1)*y[1]
  dydt[2] = y[1]
  return dydt
t_span=[0,100]
y0 = [0.999,0.001,0] #初期条件
t = np.linspace(t_span[0], t_span[1], 400)
sol = scipy.integrate.solve_ivp(func, t_span, y0, t_eval=t)
t1 = sol.t
y0 = sol.y[0,:]
y1 = sol.y[1,:]
y2 = sol.y[2,:]
t2 = np.linspace(0, 10, 400)
plt.plot(t1, y1, label="R_0 = 1.3")

plt.legend() # 凡例を表示
plt.title("Kermac & MacKendric equations")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**typoが原因ですね。**
8行目が本来なら`R0=1.3`とピリオドで浮動小数点数となるべきところを、`R0=1,3`とカンマになって (1,3) のtupleになっています。
それがエラーメッセージの基になっています。